# "[Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]Invalid parameter number" error

Tags: sql, excel, parameters

I have a multi level BOM query that works just fine when I input one of our item numbers in it. I wanted to put it into excel though and change use an excel cell as the where parameter. When I do that I always get the Invalid parameter number error below.

[Invalid Parameter Error][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDLHS.png

Here is my code

```
WITH BOMCTE AS (
SELECT 
    I.[item_no] AS [Parent]
    ,I.item_desc_1 AS [ParentDesc]
    ,I.item_desc_2 AS [ParentDesc2]
    ,0 AS [Level]
    ,BOM.[comp_item_no] AS [Component]
    ,i2.item_desc_1 AS [ComponentDesc]
    ,i2.item_desc_2 AS [ComponentDesc2]
    ,BOM.[qty_per_par] AS [QtyPer]
    ,i2.pur_or_mfg AS MakeBuy
    ,i2.user_fld_6 AS Department
    ,i2.user_fld_7 AS WorkCenter
    ,i2.user_fld_8 AS RunTime
    ,i2.user_fld_9 AS Resources
FROM [100].[dbo].[imitmidx_sql] AS I
INNER JOIN [100].[dbo].[bmprdstr_sql] AS BOM
    ON BOM.[item_no] = I.[item_no]
JOIN [100].[dbo].[imitmidx_sql] AS I2
    ON I2.item_no = BOM.comp_item_no
WHERE I.[item_no] = '102-004'

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    I.[item_no] AS [Parent]
    ,I.item_desc_1 AS [ParentDesc]
    ,I.item_desc_2 AS [ParentDesc2]
    ,BOMCTE.[Level] + 1 AS [Level]
    ,BOM.[comp_item_no] AS [Component]
    ,i2.item_desc_1 AS [ComponentDesc]
    ,i2.item_desc_2 AS [ComponentDesc2]
    ,BOM.[qty_per_par] AS [QtyPer]
    ,i2.pur_or_mfg AS MakeBuy
    ,i2.user_fld_6 AS Department
    ,i2.user_fld_7 AS WorkCenter
    ,i2.user_fld_8 AS RunTime
    ,i2.user_fld_9 AS Resources
FROM BOMCTE 
INNER JOIN [100].[dbo].[imitmidx_sql] AS I 
    ON BOMCTE.[Component] = I.[item_no] 
INNER JOIN [100].[dbo].[bmprdstr_sql] AS BOM 
    ON BOM.[item_no] = I.[item_no]
JOIN [100].[dbo].[imitmidx_sql] AS I2
    ON I2.item_no = BOM.comp_item_no
    )
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: btw the link there is not working, try fixing it

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDLHS.png